# Looking for a Silex Exception Override

Tags: silex

Silex seems to hijack the exceptions thrown anywhere in the app.  My problem with this is I have a user_db_interface class I use to pass/get user data from my database that is basically ignored once an exception is thrown.

For example if I have a duplicate user email entry that generates a PDOException, instead of being able to handle that exception within my class, I have to add an error handling closure outside of my class.  I'd rather deal with the exception internally so that I can act on this exception and continue with my script.

Any such thing as an exception override or bypass?

Here is an example:

```
###### PROVIDER REG #######
// I'M LOADING DOCTRINE "NATURALLY" AND NOT REGISTERING IT WITH $APP IN HOPES OF 
// AVOIDING THE EXCEPTION HIJACKING.
################################################################### LOAD DOCTRINE NATURAL

require 'vendor/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Doctrine', __DIR__ . '/../vendor');
$classLoader->register();

$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver'    => 'pdo_mysql',
    'dbname'    => 'MY_DB',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'password'  =>  'MY_PASS',
    'user'      => 'MY_USER',
);

$driver = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver;
$connection = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection($connectionOptions, $driver);

###################################################################### LOAD MY EXTENSION
$app['autoloader']->registerNamespaces(array('TableTrackPro' => __DIR__,));

$app->register(new TableTrackPro\ClientDBInterfaceExtension(),array('app'=>$app));
$app['client_db_interface']->set_connection($connection);


##################################################
##################################################

#################################################  MY DB INTERFACE CLASS (stripped for clarity)

namespace TableTrackPro;

class ClientDBInterface{

    private $_connection;

    public function set_connection($connection){
        $this->_connection = $connection;
    }

    public function insert_client($clientInfo){
        // SET RETURN OBJECT
        $returnObject['status'] = 'ok';     // default return status
        $returnObject['message'] = false;


// SANITIZE CLIENT INFO ETC...

 // THIS IS WHERE I WOULD LIKE TO HANDLE MY OWN EXCEPTIONS
    try{
        $this->_connection->insert('clients', $clientInfo);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
       // HANDLE EXCEPTION HERE
    }
    return json_encode($returnObject);
}


#### END CLASS #####


### CONTROLLERS ####

$app->post('/postNewClient', function () use($app){
    $clientInfo = $_POST;
    $returnObject = $app['client_db_interface']->insert_client($clientInfo);
    return json_encode($returnObject);  // <-- I handle this object with javascript via an AJAX call
});
```

Instead of handling the PDOException in my class so that I can return data as I wish, I have to add an error handler to the controller area like:

```
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) {
   // error handling code, I'd now have to handle any client-db specific errors outside of my client_db class...
});
```

I'd like to avoid this because if the exception handling were internal to the client_db class, I would know that the error was also specific to that action and I wouldn't have to write an error parser.

Comment: It's kind of hard to tell where you are trying to catch the error. Can you show a minimal example with an `app.php` and `MyClass.php`, and explain where you want to catch the error?

Comment: @igorw, I've added a little example to the question above.  Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, so the only thing silex does is catch the exception during the `$app->run()` call. There is nothing in there preventing you from catching the exception yourself earlier.

I suspect that your issue is caused by the following. Assuming your code is actually:

```
try{
    $this->_connection->insert('clients', $clientInfo);
}catch(PDOException $e){
   // HANDLE EXCEPTION HERE
}
```

Well, the issue is that you're in a namespaced class. This means that all class names are relative to the current namespace. To reference the global namespace you need to `use` them or prefix them with `\`.

What you need to do is:

```
try{
    $this->_connection->insert('clients', $clientInfo);
}catch(\PDOException $e){
   // HANDLE EXCEPTION HERE
}
```

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Interesting.  My index.php file has the require and $app->run().  I imagine then I have to intercept my request with a script that DOESN'T have the $app->run() call.  Let me give it a try and I'll let you know.

Comment: As I said, exceptions are caught really late. If you have a try-catch block higher up in the stack, it should work just fine. Not changes to the way `$app->run()` works should be necessary.

Comment: Igor, You are 100% correct, it wasn't even the $app->run call, it was the fact that I was in a namespaced class and not using the "\".

Comment: This has been giving me so much grief. The \ at the beginning solved it for me. THANK YOU!

Comment: I feel pretty dumb. I just had this problem again in another part of my application and went searching for a solution. I was so thrilled to find this answer and went to upvote it. Oh, I've already upvoted it. Can't do it again. Duh. Maybe I'll remember the answer this time.